# How to clean the sandbox every time I run the applications?

Tags: ios, xcode, sandbox

I am wondering if I could clean up sandbox everytime I run the application. I don't want to clean and rebuild every time since it takes long time.

Comment: What are you putting in the application sandbox that needs to be cleaned up? What impact is it having on your app?

Answer (score 3):

Delete the app off the device/simulator. That deletes the entire sandbox environment. Deleting off the target device/sim is independent of doing a clean. Clean deletes compiled object files and the app from the Xcode build directory, which is separate from deleting it from the device/sim.

Comment: Clean and Build, Reset contents and settings of simulator, are the only methods that can restart the sand box, so the proper answer is there is no way to do it other than that, now you could try deleting derived data, which would delete temp files and thus technically reset them but then that's a process you would have to go through each time before running the app which would slow down your QA

Comment: @A'saDickens Simply deleting the app from the simulator or device is another way to reset the sandbox since the app will be installed into a fresh sandbox. There is no need to reset the simulator or no need to do a clean build. As stated in the the answer, a clean build has nothing at all to do with clearing the sandbox. Two very different and independent things.

Comment: If I delete the app from simulator, then reinstall it again. Would the keychain be preserved? Or the reinstall is in a new sandbox and won't retrieve anything from previous runs of the sam app? @rmaddy

Comment: @Honey The keychain isn't part of the sandbox. I know on a real device, the keychain survives an app delete and reinstall. So I think it will on the simulator too.

Comment: @rmaddy Not part of the sandbox. Ohhk. So is it that the app using keychain should *update* whatever values it is setting to an empty string? Any other way to nuke the keychain? I'm asking this because my username-password isn't persisting and I am not sure if it's because how I wrote my code wrong OR is it because the way I delete/clean the app/device...

Comment: @Honey You should post your own question.

Comment: Note: This seems to not be the case with Subscription in-app purchases. Receipts persist app deletion (likely stored in keychain)

Answer (score 1):

Clean and rebuild *doesn't* delete the application data stored on the simulator by the previous runs of the app. Clean and rebuild only cleans away and rebuilds the executable before sending it to the device.

To delete the sandbox app data, you can select "Reset contents and settings of simulator" in Simulator menu, or properly delete the app from the simulator.

**If you want to clean the simulator stored data more easily, there are a few helpers:**

- http://simpholders.com iOS app that creates a system tray icon that allows you to wipe simulator data per app (or uninstall apps entirely)
- http://swinden.com/ios-simulator-folders-alfred-workflow Alfred workflow which gives you the same kind of options as the above
- http://markstruzinski.com/blog/2012/05/02/quick-wipe-of-ios-simulator-using-alfred Another Alfred workflow, simpler than the previous

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you found the solution but i'll share what I've created:

**but be warned this will always wipe your iOS Simulator apps**

At first you need to this bash script [Gist: Clean iOS Simulator Apps](https://gist.github.com/brunogama/8899208)

and then you need to configure a behaviour in the Xcode like I did in this screenshot. When the run finishes I've set the script to be executed.
[image]

If you need to clean a specific app you should create a clean script for each app you need to clean, it will look like this:

```
pkill -9 -fi simulator  2>/dev/null
_WD="$HOME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator"
find "$_WD" -iname "TheApp.app" | while read l; do
    f=$(dirname "$l")
    rm -rf "$f"
    unset f
done
unset _WD
```

in the find command you will change the parameter "TheApp.app" to the app you need to remove.
(Not tested).

Answer (score -1):

Create a directory called 'dev' and store everything in that (as if it was your documents folder). At launch, delete it if it exists?